# How to format date parsed from ASPX JSON via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, chart.js

Actually i'm parsing some data from MySQL then i serialize them as JSON.
The next step is where i retrive the JSON via AJAX and put the data in a Chart.JS.

The issue is that the date values are formatted as

> /Date(154564434687)/

Here is the JQuery code where i set the values to the chart from parsed JSON

```
 function GetMOV() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "index.aspx/GetMOV",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {

                data = r.d;
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data)

                new Chart(document.getElementById("linechart"), {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: data.map(f => f.text),
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "Venduto",
                                data: data.map(f => f.value),
                                fill: false,
                                borderColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
                                lineTension: 0.1,
                                borderWidth: 3,
                                pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                                borderCapStyle: 'square',
                                borderJoinStyle: 'square',
                                pointHitRadius: 20,
                                pointStyle: 'circle',
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        legend: { display: false },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    min: 0
                                },
                                time: {
                                    unit: 'year'
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                OnFailure(error);
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: On which line are you setting the date value to chart?

Comment: @SonalBorkar  labels: data.map(f => f.text) here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: @Rob i've yet tryed something like  new Date(data.map(f=>f.text) it doesn't work as it's not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Using map keyword with function]

I have just tried some line of codes. Do you want like this?

```
var data = [{value: 4111.47, text: "/Date(1540159200000)/"} ,{value: 5122.85, text: "/Date(1540245600000)/"} ,{value: 3906.24, text: "/Date(1540332000000)/"} ,{value: 3749.79, text: "/Date(1540418400000)/"} , {value: 6349.68, text: "/Date(1540504800000)/"}];
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}
data.map(c=>ToJavaScriptDate(c.text))
```

Comment: This is a function, can you move this function above function GetMOV()?

Comment: I just was setting it to the wrong variable, that's works thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function

```
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}

ToJavaScriptDate("/Date(154564434687)/")
"11/25/1974"
```

Comment: Can you put your full data here?

Comment: 10: {value: 4111.47, text: "/Date(1540159200000)/"}
11: {value: 5122.85, text: "/Date(1540245600000)/"}
12: {value: 3906.24, text: "/Date(1540332000000)/"}
13: {value: 3749.79, text: "/Date(1540418400000)/"}
14: {value: 6349.68, text: "/Date(1540504800000)/"}

Answer (score 1):

You also can use momentjs library.

```
var yourdate = "/Date(154564434687)/";
moment(Number(yourdate.match(/\d+/)[0])).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
"11/25/1974"
```

Comment: There is just a problem i have an array with a lot of data not a single string